# Cannot login to my developer edition (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: redirect, login-errors, developer-edition

How does one get around this persistent issue of too many redirects?

Here are the list of ways I tried to resolve the issue:

1. Login via Google Chrome (normal & incognito mode)
2. Login via Microsoft Edge
3. Login via Firefox
4. Restarting Computer
5. Clearing ALL cookies

All the above methods did not solve my issue and gives the image below :

[image]

Nevertheless I somehow can login to success.salesforce.com and trailhead.salesforce.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that it already had a session id to my own personal Macbook. Trying to login via my work laptop caused this ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

If all other troubleshooting fails (like clear cache and whatnot), just login with the 1st computer you logged in with.